# Filter a text file based on matching values in another file

Tags: matlab, text, merge, cygwin, multiple-columns

I would like to merge some text files in cygwin or matlab based on matching timestamps;

I have one file with a column of time stamps:

file 1:

```
7,
486,
730,
1031,
1331,
1631,
1931,
2231,
...
100000
```

and file 2; with 3 columns and a different time stamp(1hz) :

```
1 data1 data2,
2 data1 data2,
3 data1 data2,
4 data1 data2,
....
100000 data1 data2
```

I would like to merge the files based on matching timestamps such that I preserve file1, column 1:

```
7    data1 data2,
486  data1 data2,
730  data1 data2,
1031 data1 data2,
1331 data1 data2,
...
```

thanks

Comment: are your `data1` and `data2` columns numeric values or are they text strings ?

Comment: all number, no text. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main function you have to use in Matlab for your case is : [`ismember`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html).

It will return the indices (line number) of the timestamp in file 2 (data file) which match the timestamps from file 1 (timestamp only).

obviously, read your data first, do you merging, then write the output file.

```
timestamp1 = dlmread('textfile1.txt') ;         %// read timestamp only file
DATA       = dlmread('textfile2.txt') ;         %// read DATA file
timestamp2 = DATA(:,1) ;                        %// Extract timestamp from DATA (optional)

commonIndex = ismember(timestamp2,timestamp1) ; %// Find common timestamps line index in file 2
MergedData = DATA(commonIndex,:) ;              %// build common matrix

dlmwrite('MergedData.txt',MergedData,'Delimiter',' ')   %// write output file
```

Comment: you should be aware this is not a merged file, but actually a filtered version of textfile2.txt with only lines remaining starting with a timestamp from textfile1.txt. This might be what you want, but in two years time someone might wonder where the column data3 in his textfile1.txt has gone, or the other timestamps in file1 ;-) If you really want a filter this is a clean way to do it with numerical data only.

Comment: @hugovdberg. I agree with the semantics, "merged" is not the right word to describe this operation (the title of the question could be changed to better respect that). However, I think the description of the actual operation to execute was clear enough in the text of the question (so the OP seemed to know what he wanted, and he's aware that some lines will be dropped in the process because that's what he asked for) and apparently the answer satisfied him. _ps: there was no column_ `data3` _in the first text file, nor in the second one._

Comment: @Hoki true, but the philosophy of stackoverflow is to provide generic solutions which could help others as well, and therefore I thought it best to point it out for future readers :-) Your solution definitely does what the OP asked for! (and the data3 column was just a hypothetical example, sorry for the confusion)

Comment: @hugovdberg. You're right. I was hoping the OP would change the title itself but he probably didn't get notified of these comments because they are on my answer (not on his post) ... so i just changed it myself. Hope it's clearer this way.